# In a C# project, what is a ReferenceFromRuntime

Tags: c#, .net-core

In the C# project file for WCF on .NET Core, I'm seeing entries like this:

```
<ReferenceFromRuntime Include="System.Private.ServiceModel" />
<ReferenceFromRuntime Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" />
<ReferenceFromRuntime Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" />
<ReferenceFromRuntime Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" />
<ReferenceFromRuntime Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" />
```

What is a ReferenceFromRuntime? Right now it just appears as a missing file so I assume I'm missing some plugin.

Comment: Looks like its undocumented.

Comment: Likely something to do with this? https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/referenceFromRuntime.targets

Comment: Could be, but I don't know if `ReferenceFromRuntime` is being defined by that as a project-specific concept or if `ReferenceFromRuntime` is a standard concept that's being configured by it.